# Navbar Collapse items not aligned

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar collapse button but the items in the dropdown aren't aligned. I think it is something to do with how I have the divs setup. How do I resolve?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light mb-4 row">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="col-4 text-left collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_candidate">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">A Better Candidate</a>
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_employer">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">A Better Employer</a>
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_stuff">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Better Stuff</a>
          </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'a_better_place:home' %}">
            A Better Place
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 text-right collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item" id="about_us">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> About Us </a>
              <li class="nav-item" id="contact">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'a_better_place:contact' %}">
                      Contact
                  </a>   
          </ul>
          
      </div>
</nav>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW09y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `col` and `row` aren’t used in the navbar, and if you’re going to have two `navbar-collapse` lists, you can’t give them the same ID. Instead, you can use a class and use that class name in the navbar-toggler’s `data-target`.

To have the branding in the center on larger screens, you can use flex order.

FYI – when posting a question, it’s best to include a functional snippet so people can see the problem.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light mb-4">
    <!-- get rid of row -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand order-md-2 " href="{% url 'a_better_place:home' %}">
        A Better Place
    </a>
    <!-- can't have dual IDs -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dual-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_candidate">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">A Better Candidate</a>
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_employer">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">A Better Employer</a>
            <li class="nav-item" id="better_stuff">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Better Stuff</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- drop the div around brand -->

    <!-- remove col-4 text-right -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dual-navbar-collapse order-md-3">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" id="about_us">
                <a class="nav-link" href=""> About Us </a>
            <li class="nav-item" id="contact">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'a_better_place:contact' %}">
                    Contact
                </a>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```